# How to fix adb backup return 41 bytes

Tags: android, adb

These are the two commands that I always use to get SQLite file from Android device to view and debug.

```
$ adb backup -noapk com.example.app
$ dd if=backup.ab bs=1 skip=24 | python -c "import zlib,sys;sys.stdout.write(zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.read()))" | tar -xvf -
```

However, I don't why now I cannot use it. the back.ab I got from the first command will be 41 bytes and the second command will not work. The commands still work for other apps though. Only problem with this app I am working with.

I have tried a solution in [this link](https://raccoon.io/android-adb-backup-41-bytes-549-bytes-bug-fix/) but it's the same. I vaguely remember that I face this problem before because I am doing something wrong like typo in package name. This time I double check and my package name is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that this problem caused by having `android:allowBackup="false"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, which I added to stop Auto Backup for Apps while I'm developing my app.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

So just remove the line and the `$adb backup` will work again